# Drupal Commerce "product type" vs kickstart "variation type"

Tags: commerce

I am new to online shops creation, and I am looking at Drupal Commerce and its popular distribution package, Drupal Kickstart.

I understand more or less the concept behind "product type" in Drupal Commerce, but Kickstart uses different terminology - "product variation type". Is it the same thing? Is there difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Product variations types within Drupal Commerce Kickstart are the same as product types referenced by vanilla Drupal Commerce.

I think the label changed within Kickstart so that it is a little less ambigious.